# Can not remove the file during unison sync

Tags: linux, macos, synchronization, unison

I have setup unison between Mac and Linux (both version 2.48.4) and sync-ing files is just fine. The problem is when I try to remove a file in one location, the file is not removed in the other location. Rather than that, the file is re-created in the original location I tried delete. This is happening in both Mac/Linux when I tried to delete there.

I used file-sync method for periodic sync and fsmonitor, and both have the same behavior. And, I know there is -nodeletion which prevents unison to remove the file, and I don't use this option at all. And at the moment, I have no clue why this is keep happening.

Do you have any suggestion to move forward?

Comment: Weird. Your system clocks are accurate I assume? Could you post a minimal unison profile that produces this issue?

Comment: Hi, did you solve this issue? Any update on it?

Answer (score 0):

The `-ignorearchives` flag will force this behavior. Check your command, default.prf, or script for this flag and remove it to enable syncs for file deletion, class file name change, etc.